# What does the macro “#define requires (...)" means?

Tags: c++, macros

Recently I'm reading the book "Elements of Programming", and I found this macro in its source code.

I also found a similar question here but it is not same with this exactly.

Here is a piece of code about this:

```
#define requires(...)

template<typename T>
requires(Regular(T))
void construct(T& p)
{
// Precondition: $p$ refers to raw memory, not an object
// Postcondition: $p$ is in a default-constructed state
new (&p) T();
}
```

I want to know what "#define requires(...)" means, and why write in this way.

Comment: It means that someone is trying too hard.

Comment: @PeteBecker Not helpful

Comment: @PeteBecker I am sorry I dont get the point of your comment..English is not my first language..

Comment: My point was that whoever wrote that macro was trying to be clever but ended up with something silly. It's just a confusing way to write a comment.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, I guess the author want describe this more similar to math .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [Elements of Programming](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/book.html) is written by Alexander Stepanov, the father of the STL, and Paul McJones.

The `requires` notation is described in chapter 1.  The current necessary implementation — the `#define requires(...)` macro — is described in Appendix B.2.  The semantic description of what it represents in the book is given on page 13 (two footnotes omitted):

> An *abstract* procedure is parameterized by types and constant values, with the requirements on those parameters.  We use function templates and function object templates.  The parameters follow the `template` keyword and are introduced by `typename` for types and `int` or another integral type for constant values.  Requirements are specified via the `requires` clause, whose argument is an expression built up from constant values, concrete types, formal parameters, applications of type attributes and type functions, equality of values and types, concepts, and logical connectives<sup>7</sup>.
>
> Here is an example of an abstract procedure:
>
> ```
> template<typename Op>
>     requires(BinaryOperation(Op))
> Domain(Op) square(const Domain(Op)& x, Op op)
> {
>     return op(x, x);
> }
> ```

The concept of a BinaryOperation is defined on p31.  The concept of `Domain(Op)` is introduced on p12.

The empty macro for `requires` is necessary because C++ does not yet have the support needed to implement it fully.  At the moment, therefore, it acts as a documentary aid and is not something that a C++ compiler can act on.  But there is little doubt that C++17 will get a lot closer to being able to handle it.

The book is very interesting, but it's also very compact and hard to comprehend at times.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define requires(...)
```

expands to nothing.

Technical: the ellipsis `...` lets this macro take a variable number of arguments, which is necessary for using template expressions with commas directly as arguments.

It is apparently used to indicate requirements on a template, like future C++ “concepts”. However, the lowercase name can easily conflict with other things (macros don't respect scopes), and code using it will anyway have to be double-checked if or when C++ gains concepts support, so it has some severe drawbacks and no advantage over plain *comments*.

Comment: Thank U, and I just understood this after I publish this question...hahha this question looks stupid and thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is someone's way of defining pre-requisites. The define creates a macro that takes any number of arguments and results in no code. They then use their own nomenclature to specify what requirements are required.

They probably intend to use this to later support concepts or some other contract system when it is added to c++

Answer (score 1):

It's a 'fancy' way of making a comment.  After running through the preprocessor that code looks like:

```
template<typename T>

void construct(T& p)
{


new (&p) T();
}
```

Perhaps it would be clearer if they wrote:

```
#define requires(this_doesnt_appear_to_the_right_so_the_result_is_nothing)
```

but that's a bit log-winded and pedantic.